# How speed up woocommerce_product_query in meta_query?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I use following code to add custom query to woocommerce products when page loaded:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', '_fn_test', 10, 1 );
    function _fn_test($q){
        $meta_query = $q->get( 'meta_query' );
        
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key'       => '_stock_status',
            'value'     => 'outofstock',
            'compare'   => '!='
        );
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key'       => 'custom_stock', // this is my custom meta option in product_meta table
            'value'     => '0',
            'compare'   => '!='
        );
        
        $q->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
    }
```

but it reduce the speed a lot in shop page, is there any problems in function? how can I speed it up?

Comment: You are adding 2 postmeta joins to the final sql. Can you do it with only one? Cb you use only 'custom_stock' key? If you can use only your custom meta and get the same results,then remove the '_stock_status' from query. But you have to be sure that you can't have outofstock and custom_stock  != 0 at the same time. That should speed up things a little

Answer (score 0):

I usually prefer the wp_cache_* functions to cache the results of the query allowing you to avoid running the query on every page load and instead use a cached version of the results, which should be much faster.

Other things that you could do:-

1.Consider using a more efficient way to perform the query, such as using the WP_Query class or custom MySQL query.

2.Optimize your database(make sure that your indexes are properly set up to support  query).

3.Consider using a plugin or service to optimize your site's performance, such as W3 Total Cache or Cloudflare.

Note:-There may be other factors too affecting the performance of your site, such as the number and size of images, the number of plugins you have installed, and the complexity of your theme. Identifying and addressing these issues can also help improve the performance of your site.

Comment: Thanks @divyavinod6, as you siad I will test MySQL query, but how can I show query result in woocommece shop page i.e. how return result?